# mat-datepicker rendering below the content

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material2

My material design datepicker in Angular is rendering below the content.

I have one component that is a part of the module and rendered inside app-root. Inside that I have mat-stepper, and inside one step I have mat-datepicker.

This i how the component apporx. looks like:

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper #stepper>
     <mat-step>
        <div data-component="app-root">
          <section>
            ...
              <mat-form-ifield>
                    <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
                    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
                    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
                  </mat-form-ifield>
            ...
```

And, when I inspect the page I see the following:

```
<head>
 <body>
  <app-root>
   <my component here>
  <couple of scripts>
  <div class="cdk-overlay-container>...</div> (this is where the datepicker is rendered)
```

I guess that I can fix this by editing the css for cdk-overlay-container class, but it doesn't seem to be the right way. What seems to be the problem here?

[image]

Comment: It looks like somehow you've messed up with some styles... Do you think you are able to build a bare-bones reproduction on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/pbqjqmvdagr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmaterial-module.ts)?

Answer (score 1):

From the information given in the question, this appears to be a problem caused by a high z-index value given for cdk-overlay. Try to reduce the z-index value. Also if possible please add the cdk-overlay and other date picker associated css classes in the question itself for better code clarity.

Comment: Part of your suggestion holds true for my issue.  My scenario is that I am attempting to utilize the `mat-datepicker` inside of `mat-sidenav-content` . The rendering is completely broken (the datepicker is positioned incorrectly, and the z-index of the overlay is incorrect)